# Android Picasso Library NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, picasso

i'm new with Picasso library and i'm not sure to put in the context argument of with(context) method, i tried both this + getApplicationContext() and it failed any help would be appreciated

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.appertizers_curly_twister_fries).into(iv);

}
```

Comment: Hi, will you try: with(this.getBaseContext())

Comment: Internally i believe Picasso uses whatever context you give it and calls getApplicationContext() on it.  [Here](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java)  line 724

Comment: it didn't work either i'm afraid

Comment: You should add `setLoggingEnabled(true)` to picasso call just for now to check and make sure the image request is going through. Remember to remove it when your done debugging.

Comment: yes thnx it worked fine after adding setLoggingEnabled(true)